# Spring Security cannot find DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring Boot and Spring Security, and I am trying to set up Spring Security to use my login credentials from MySQL database.

SecurityConfig class:

```
   @Service
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
            .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username as username, enabled as authority FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    }
}
```

spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="userDaoImpl" class="com.watchdog.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <!--<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bsbuckne" />-->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I believe my problem is that my dataSource is not being recognized. The stack trace I am getting is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:355) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

If I change the authentication type to in-memory and manually set a username & password the authentication works.

The reason I am so confused is because I am using this same setDataSource method in a different DAO class that is handling all of my database CRUD operations and it is working as expected. What is keeping my SecurityConfig class from finding my dataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have your tried annotate:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

or

```
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the first definitely. I think since I am using XML approach rather than an annotated datasource bean simply autowiring the datasource has not been working out for me.

Comment: The second method, however, I had not considered. It seems to be working, however I am getting a red squiggly in my IDE saying that "no beans of 'datasource' type can be found". My stack trace is no longer coming up though, so it may just be IntelliJ.

Comment: I'm another one struggling with this issue in Intellij IDEA where I thought the warning was a real compilation error. Anyway, when I started up the app even with the error in the IDE, it worked fine.